# How does one use `removeAllObjects` in a `RLMArray`

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How does one use `removeAllObjects` in a `RLMArray`?
I get an error of `'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to mutate a readOnly RLMArray'`.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property RLMArray *list;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _list = [Person allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@", _list);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender {
    Person *human = [[Person alloc] init];
    human.name = @"John";
    human.title = @"Wizard";

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:human];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

}

- (IBAction)removePerson:(id)sender {
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [_list removeAllObjects];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't much know what is going on ,but you are using `[_list removeAllObjects]`
but before that you are using `[realm addPerson];`
maybe it is something in here ?

Comment: I mean , maybe you should use `[realm removeAllObjects];` , Sorry if it is not helped I just tried

Comment: Try `[realm deleteObjects:_list];` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% positive, but i think that this should work.

```
- (IBAction)removePerson:(id)sender {
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm deleteObjects:_list];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Realm are you using?  As of [v0.87.0](http://realm.io/news/realm-cocoa-0.87.0/), queries return an [`RLMResults`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMResults.html) object, as opposed to an [`RLMArray`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMArray.html).  This includes the [`allObjects`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/allObjects) method of [`RLMObject`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html) that you are using in your `viewDidLoad:` method. I would change the type of your `list` property to [`RLMResults`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMResults.html) and do what rj001 suggests and calling the [`deleteObjects:`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/deleteObjects:) method on the [`RLMRealm`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html) object.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael McGuire said, `+allObjects` now returns an RLMResults, which doesn't respond to `-removeAllObjects`, but more importantly, `removeAllObjects` only removes the *links* to the objects that are contained in the RLMArray, not the objects themselves.

So if you want to delete the objects (which of course also removes any links to them) you should use `-deleteObjects:` on the RLMRealm instance. It seems like this is what you want to do in this case.